# Usb hub is not able to extinguish peripherals

Tags: hub, safely-remove-hardware

I have a problem. Few days ago I have bought new active hub (LogiLink UA0096). Hub recognizes devices rightly and I can use them. Unfortunately, Hub is not able to eject them properly. After the ejection Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (on my ASUS N65VZ) announces that device can be safely removed, but hub still powers the peripheral and LED control proves it. Normally, power should be cut off, external HD (for example) should spin down. And then removal would be possible.

I checked whether the same problem exists when computer is booted directly from Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander Live CD. It doesn't. Hub can extinguish devices properly. LED controls turns off as they should. So, hardware problem can be excluded. I checked the hub as well on my small netbook (Acer Aspire One AOD260) powered by Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bit. Everything works properly. Computer can cut off energy from the given usb port of the described hub.

So, I reinstalled the Generic USB Hub drivers on my ASUS computer. It did not solve the issue. I know that presumably installing Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit from scratch could be helpful as well as so-called in-place upgrade. However, until now, my Windows haven't found any integrity violations. Actually, I want not to reinstall Windows or execute in-place upgrade. It would be too time consuming.

Help me find less invasive method, please.

Comment: Your question is really confusing.  Are you plugging in USB 3.0 devices into the 3.0 HUB connection to the 2.0 ports?  if thats the case that would cause lots of issues.

Comment: No. I plugged USB 2.0 and 3.0 devices into USB 2.0 downstream ports of my hub, which on its own is connected to USB 3.0 port of computer. I think it is not the problem, because USB 3.0 is compatible with 2.0. As I described, when hub is connected to my netbook via his 2.0 usb port everything works.

It seems not to be a hardware problem. Under Ubuntu Live CD everything goes right. So, my post scriptum was unnecessary and misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. After pretty long examination **it turned out that hub couldn't extinguish the devices because was blocked by following Windows' updates: KB2903939, KB2911134, KB2887595, KB2914218, KB2911134, KB2911106, KB2917929, KB2903939, KB2898514 and KB2917929. The last one neutralized also selective suspending of usb devices.** It is worth noting that listed patches are not security updates.

Answer (score 1):

"Safely remove hardware" tells Windows 2 things:

- Flush all outstanding data to disk, in particular modified files which are in the file cache.
- Stop using the drive, and remove the driveletter so all applications stop too.

powering down isn't one of those two, but USB drives may still decide to do so.

Comment: Quote: "but USB drives may still decide to do so".

So, explain me why in safe mode they "decide" and in normal don't, please. :)

Comment: Well, Windows stops issuing disk commands, for instance. But consider those USB led lights: Windows doesn't bother talking to them at all, and they still can draw USB power, so it definitely is available.

Comment: You are wrong. Let's assume that only 5V control (attached to no piece of electronics) is connected to the USB port. It is lit because port is powered. But this control (receiver) can't decide to be suspended on its own, because energy (and signals created from it) is under administration of OS/host (sender). The latter manages when and where energy can be cut. But this is a matter of minor importance. I have solved my problem.